# Using class in c++

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to use classes but the program won't run. How can it be fixed? Keep in mind I'm a beginner in c++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>// enable writing to and reading from files
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
//Globals
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Person
{
public:
    Person() {cout<<"\n\tBuilding a Person.";}
    ~Person() {cout<<"\n\tDestroying a Person.";}
    //Accessor Methods
    void setPersonName(string X) {PersonName=X; }
    void setOccupation(string X) {Occupation=X; }
    void setLocation(string X) {Location=X; }
    void setReferences(string X) {References=X; }
    string GetPersonName() {return PersonName;}
    string GetOccupation() {return Occupation;}
    string GetLocation() {return Location;}
    string GetReferences() {return References;}
private:
    string PersonName ;
    string Occupation ;
    string Location;
    string References;
};//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Function prototypes
void createperson();
void editperson();
void displayperson();
void saveperson();
void loadperson();
Person*CG;
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char choose[10] = "";
    CG = new Person ();
    cout<<"\n\t Personnel database 1.0\n";
    //system ("CLS");
    while (choose [0] != 'q')
    {
        system ("CLS");
        cout<<"\n\t---------------------Main Menu---------------------\n";
        cout<<"\n\t| |\n";
        cout<<"\n\t| (c) Create person |\n";
        cout<<"\n\t| (E) edit information |\n";
        cout<<"\n\t| (D) display person |\n";
        cout<<"\n\t| (S) Save person |\n";
        cout<<"\n\t| (L) Load person |\n";
        cout<<"\n\t| (Q) quit |\n";
        cout<<"\n\t| |\n";
        cout<<"\n\t---------------------------------------------------\n\n\t";
        cin>>choose;
        //system ("CLS");
        switch (choose [0])
        {
            //system ("CLS");
        case 'c': createperson(); break;
        case 'e': editperson(); break;
        case 'd': displayperson(); system ("pause"); break;
        case 's': saveperson(); break;
        case 'l': loadperson(); break;
        case 'q': cout<<"\n\tExiting main menu..."; break;
        default :"\n\tInvalid input!";
        }
    }
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
void createPerson()
{
    CG=new Person();
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void editPerson()
{
    string TEMP;
    system ("CLS");
    cout<<"\n\n\t---------------------EDIT person ---------------------------";
    cout<<"\n\t NAME: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline (cin,TEMP);
    CG->setPersonName(TEMP);
    cout<<"\n\t Occupation: ";
    getline (cin,TEMP);
    CG->setOccupation(TEMP);
    cout<<"\n\t Location: ";
    getline (cin,TEMP);
    CG->setLocation(TEMP);
    cout<<"\n\t References: ";
    getline (cin,TEMP);
    CG->setReferences(TEMP);
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void displayPerson()
{
    system("CLS");
    cout<<"\n\n\t---------------------person information----------------------";
    cout<< "\n\tName: "<<CG->GetPersonName();
    cout<< "\n\tOccupation: "<<CG->GetOccupation();
    cout<< "\n\tLocation: "<<CG->GetLocation();
    cout<< "\n\tReferences: "<<CG->GetReferences();
    cout<<"\n\n\t---------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void savePerson()
{
    try
    {
        ofstream DATAFILE;
        DATAFILE.open("Data1.file",ios::out);
        DATAFILE <<CG->GetPersonName ()<<"\n";
        DATAFILE <<CG->GetOccupation ()<<"\n";
        DATAFILE <<CG->GetLocation ()<<"\n";
        DATAFILE <<CG->GetReferences ()<<"\n";
        DATAFILE.close(); //Prevents data from getting corrupt incase of sudden shutdown
        cout<<"\n\t Success! Data was saved to file.";
    }
    catch (exception x)
    {
        cout<<"\n\t File Error! Could not SAVE PERSON.";
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void loadperson()
{
    try
    {
        string TEMP;
        ifstream DATAFILE;
        DATAFILE.open("Data1.file",ios::in);
        getline (DATAFILE,TEMP);
        CG->setPersonName ();
        getline (DATAFILE,TEMP);
        CG->setOccupation ();
        getline (DATAFILE,TEMP);
        CG->setLocation ();
        getline (DATAFILE,TEMP);
        CG->setReferences ();
        DATAFILE.close();
    }
    catch (exception x)
    {
        cout<<"\n\t File Error! Unable to load data.";
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**These are the errors:**

```
5   IntelliSense: too few arguments in function call    c:\users\toshiba\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\trial and error\trial and error\bel class.cpp    136
6   IntelliSense: too few arguments in function call    c:\users\toshiba\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\trial and error\trial and error\bel class.cpp    138
7   IntelliSense: too few arguments in function call    c:\users\toshiba\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\trial and error\trial and error\bel class.cpp    140
8   IntelliSense: too few arguments in function call    c:\users\toshiba\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\trial and error\trial and error\bel class.cpp    142
```

Error   1   error C2660: 'Person::setPersonName' : function does not take 0 arguments   c:\users\toshiba\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\trial and error\trial and error\bel class.cpp    136
Error   2   error C2660: 'Person::setOccupation' : function does not take 0 arguments   c:\users\toshiba\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\trial and error\trial and error\bel class.cpp    138
Error   3   error C2660: 'Person::setLocation' : function does not take 0 arguments c:\users\toshiba\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\trial and error\trial and error\bel class.cpp    140
Error   4   error C2660: 'Person::setReferences' : function does not take 0 arguments   c:\users\toshiba\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\trial and error\trial and error\bel class.cpp    142

Comment: Well, you could start by reading the compiler errors and fixing those. Add a "storage class" or "type specifier" to whatever is at line 13, etc.

Comment: IntelliSense errors won't prevent the program from being built, usually.

Comment: @StoryTeller "IntelliSense" merely means what caught the error. The ones listed make the code pretty much uncompilable.

Answer (score 8):

The keywords `private` and `public` are spelled like so, not with capital initials.

Also, having a class Person that has a member `int Person;` seems like a good way to get some confusion going.

Comment: Thanks I fixed that but not i get a new error "too few arguments in function call". what does that mean?.....I've edited the code above

Comment: @Sara: The error message says that you are trying to invoke some function which needs n arguments, but you provide < n arguments. The offending line is also given. If you look at this line, you'll see `CG->setPersonName ();`. This means that you try to invoke the method setPersonName on an object of class Person. However, in the class Person, you only provide a method "setPersonName" which needs one parameter (the new name of the person). You probably want to pass the text that has been entered by the user of your program: `CG->setPersonName (TEMP);`
  Regards, Stuart